# The requested topic does not exist error in PHPBB

Tags: phpbb

Getting The requested topic does not exist error in PHPBB when posting reply to any forum in PHPBB forum

Answer (score 1):

This issue exists because whenever you will post the reply then your url will have &amp instead of & which is being treated as a seperate variable. So you need to add below code into your viewtopic.php file available in root folder after line number 30 :-

```
if($topic_id==0)
    $topic_id   = request_var('amp;t', 0);  

if($post_id==0)
    $post_id    = request_var('amp;p', 0);
```

Comment: Thanks Nilesh.I have been searching a solution since three weeks.